# How does the heat energy from burning a gallon of gasoline compare to the solar energy the resulting $\rm CO_2$ absorbs in the atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, atmospheric-science, climate-science

I think essentially all of the energy from a gallon of gasoline burned in, say, a car is eventually converted into heat in the atmosphere. But I don't *think* the heat from burning fossil fuels contributes in any material way to global warming -- the idea of heating the earth directly, even at the scale we currently burn fossil fuels, seems unlikely. But the earth is nonetheless warming up.

That suggests, a little counterintuitively to me, that the solar heat adsorbed by the $\rm CO_2$ generated from burning a gallon of gas must exceed the heat from burning that gallon of gas (at least over the timescale that that $\rm CO_2$ remains in the atmosphere -- Google gives me a half-life of ~120 years.) Perhaps even by a few orders of magnitude.

To put a specific point on it: what fraction of the total heat from burning a gallon of gasoline actually comes from burning the gasoline? (Over the whole lifetime of the $\rm CO_2$ in the atmosphere.)